# My application(ios) don't work in ipad. I have this error "home.html error:1" after updating of my ipad and xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

My application (IOS) don't work in iPad. I get this error after updating my i-pad and xcode:

> home.html error:1

The second application works the first time, but the second time the application crashes and I get this message:

> Received memory warning.
>   Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.

I also get this message:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I change `Info.plist` by doing the writing in here: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http), but I still get the message.

All that after updating my IOS to 9.2 and xcode 7.2.1.

Comment: Which ios did you upgrade to? At what point does the application crash? Try using [instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks) to figure out memory problems. You should update your question when you have some more details

Comment: My problem it's resolved,i just add in the file info.split: <key> NSAppTransportSecurity </ key> <dict> <key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </ key> <true /> </ dict>